# Loop for all created buttons in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        private void flowLayoutPanel1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = e.X;
            int y = e.Y;
            newBtn = new Button(); //I created private var
            newBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(78, 76);
            newBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            newBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x+62,y+80);
            newBtn.Text = "Created button";
            this.Controls.Add(newBtn);
            newBtn.BringToFront();
        }
```

Let's say that created like 10 buttons, how can I loop for all of them?
**Like:**

```
foreach(Button btn in this.Controls.list(newBtn)){
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, WebForms, something else?

Comment: It's WinForms .

Comment: Yeah exactly, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered simply making your own global `List<Button>` and add the buttons to that list? Granted, as noted already, you can do something like… `this.Controls.OfType<Button>()` … however, if you are going to loop through the collection of buttons numerous times, it makes little sense to “re-collect” the `Buttons` over and over. And what if there are buttons on the form that are used for some other purpose?

Comment: `foreach(var btn in this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x=>x is Button).ToList())
            {

            }`